# Ignoring statement names inside parameters

Tags: python, pycharm

When creating a function in PyCharm an error occurred as I tried to use a statement (in my case the *try* statement) as a parameter.

I also do get an error at second line due to Python tries to resolve the *try* as well.

```
def currency_converter_to_dkk(try):
    amount = float(try * 2.25)
    print(amount)

def currency_converter_to_try(dkk):
    amount = float(DKK * 0.4436)
    print(amount)
```

and since the PEP8 name conventions I 'cannot' change the parameter to uppercase.

Is there any way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: That's not a PyCharm problem, your code is wrong - `try` is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) and cannot be used as a parameter name. Also `try` seems like a bad name for the parameter to begin with.

Comment: "and since the PEP8 name conventions I 'cannot' change the parameter to uppercase." PEP8 also reads: "A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds". Although `try_` would still be better than `Try`.

Comment: If you are using `try` to represent the Turkish Lira, maybe use `cc_try`, `try_`, `try_curr` or something of that nature.

Comment: Also, you should probably call your functions something like `try_to_dkk` and `dkk_to_try` instead of `currency_converter_to_dkk`. Euro is a currency, but your function doesn't convert euro to dkk.

Comment: I'd do something like this: http://pastebin.com/T7SAKA08

Comment: Sorry did not see your comments haha.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know I know just out of curiosity whether if it is possible or not.

Comment: @Markusmeskanen Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try` is a keyword in Python used in [the `try` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement). You cannot use keywords as a name.

You need to use another name. Appending an underscore is a very common practice.

```
def currency_converter_to_dkk(try_):
    amount = float(try_ * 2.25)
    print(amount)
```

Comment: So there is no way to use exactly 'try' as parameter and to avoid it you simply use an underscore?

Comment: @Rakozay, You can `try` as is. Appending underscore is an example.

Comment: @Rakozay No, there is no way to use `try` as a parameter's name. Appending an underscore is a very common practice, so I wouldn't worry about using `try_` instead.

Comment: @Jonrsharpe I just thought that maybe being specific would be a great idea as I have several other currencies to convert, but I see that the parameter name can be used again and again